# Expected value of coin game

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You have four coins and I have four coins. We both throw the four and if your four sides equal to mine, I will give you 2 dollar and otherwise you give me 1. Will you do it?

I want to calculate the expected value of the game, and I'm not sure why this is wrong. Let X be the probability that we get the same four sides (and so I win the game).

X = P(I get 4H, You get 4H) + P(I Get 3H, You Get 3H) + P(I get 2H, You get 2H) + P(I get 1H, You get 1H) + P(I get 0H, you get 0H)

X = ((1/2)^4 * 4C4)^2 + ((1/2)^4 * 4C3)^2 + ((1/2)^4 * 4C2)^2 + ((1/2)^4 * 4C1)^2 + ((1/2)^4 * 4C0)^2

I have the squares to account for both of us getting the outcome.

The expected value should thus be 2*X - 1(1-X) = -.25

Why is this wrong?

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: What do you mean by "your four sides equal to mine"? Do you mean that on each throw that both coins are the same? Or do you mean that the count of head & tails is the same?

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @RossMillikan The answer is actually -46/256.

Comment: @copper.hat You both throw the four coins, and then compare afterwards (order of coins doesn't matter)

Comment: That is what I get, too, from your equation.  Try your calculator again.

Comment: @RossMillikan whattt, let me try plugging it in again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation looks fine.  I get $X=\frac {70}{256},$ which makes the value of the game $\frac{140-186}{256}=-\frac{46}{256}\approx -0.1797$.  I don't want to play.  Pay me $3$ on a win and I will play.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was just clumsy with the calculator.